# Multiplying text field with combo box Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, int, multiplication

I am fairly new to java and i was wondering how i might multiply a number a user inputs in a text box to a number they select in a combo box.
so far i have this:

```
 int Cost = Integer.parseInt(txtCost.getText());
   int TipCost;

   int Tip = Integer.parseInt((String)cboTip.getSelectedItem()); 

   TipCost = Cost*(Tip/100);
   TipCost = Math.round(TipCost);
   TipCost = TipCost/100;
```

What i get right now is just 0.

Comment: What numbers are you testing it with? Shouldn't you be using floating-point numbers like `double` and not `int`? Otherwise everything past the decimal point will be removed.

Comment: what kind of options do you have in your combo box?

Comment: i have 5, 10, 15, 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TipCost` needs to be of type `double` in order to produce numbers that have a decimal point.

Also, your calculations are suffering from integer division, which disregards remainders. Calculations that divide an integer by 100 had better be with an integer greater than 100, or else the result will always be 0.

You also have some logic errors. Here is how you should fix your code:

```
int Cost = Integer.parseInt(txtCost.getText());
int Tip = Integer.parseInt(cboTip.getSelectedItem().toString()); 

double TipCost = Cost*Tip/100.0; // get the tip cost, 100.0 avoids integer division
TipCost = Math.round(TipCost*100)/100.0; // round to 2 decimal places
```

Comment: You could simplify even further by doing `double TipCost = Math.round(Cost*Tip)/100.0;`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting the selected value, try calling a `toString()` method on the selected item, like so:

```
int Tip = Integer.parseInt(cboTip.getSelectedItem().toString());
```